# Center a 'div' in the middle of the screen, even when the page is scrolled up or down?

Tags: html, css, scroll, position, centering

I have in my page a button which when clicked displays a `div` (popup style) in the middle of my screen.

I am using the following CSS to center the `div` in the middle of the screen:

```
.PopupPanel
{
    border: solid 1px black;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 100;

    height: 400px;
    margin-top: -200px;

    width: 600px;
    margin-left: -300px;
}
```

This CSS works fine as long as the page is not scrolled down.

But, if I place the button at the bottom of my page, when it is clicked, the `div` is displayed at the top, and the user has to scroll up to view the contents of the `div`.

I would like to know how to display the `div` in the middle of the screen, even when the page has been scrolled.

Comment: question question. Why are you subtracting margin-top: (200) and margin-left. I feel this is the medium of the height and width, but why do we have to do that to get the absolute center? Shouldn't the left 50% and top 50% do the trick?

Comment: @jmoon90 The `left: 50%; top: 50%` moves the *top left corner* of the `.PopupPanel` to the center of the screen. We then move it half of the width and height back to center it's center. See [Centering on css-tricks.com](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/)

Answer (score 211, accepted):

Change the `position` attribute to `fixed` instead of `absolute`.

Comment: What about if you need to scroll the pop up div and its larger than the screen?

Comment: Keep in head that this is not the most responsive solution (but a perfect solution for the problem above). Check http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals and look with your DevTools to get some nice ideas about working with your popups/modals.

Answer (score 36):

Change `position:absolute;` to `position:fixed;`

Answer (score 19):

> **Quote**:  I would like to know how to display the div in the middle of the
>   screen, whether user has scrolled up/down.

Change

```
position: absolute;
```

To

```
position: fixed;
```

---

**W3C specifications for [`position: absolute`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#absolute-positioning) and for [`position: fixed`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#fixed-positioning).**

Answer (score 7):

Here's how to center a box in the middle of the screen even if you don't have fixed dimensions. Let's say you would like a box 60% width / 60% height. The way to make it centered is by creating 2 boxes: a "container" box that position left: 50% top :50%, and a "text" box inside with reverse position left: -50%; top :-50%;

It works and it's cross browser compatible.

Check out the code below, you probably get a better explanation:

```css
html, body {
  min-height: 100%;
}

#message {
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#message .container {
  height: 60%;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 60%;
}

#message .container .text {
  background: #fff;
  height: 100%;
  left: -50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -50%;
  width: 100%;
}

#message .bg {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 9;
}
```

```html
<div id="message">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="text">
      <h2>Warning</h2>
      <p>The message</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bg"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Correct Method is

```
.PopupPanel
{
    border: solid 1px black;
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 100;
    height: 400px;
    margin-top: -200px;

    width: 600px;
    margin-left: -300px;
}
```